# Solve the system of non-linear equations

Tags: polynomials

Solve the system $$\begin{cases}x^2 - yz = 3\\ y^2 - zx = 4\\ z^2 - xy = 5\end{cases}$$ How do I factorize the equation obtained on combining these equations?

Comment: Could you show what you have done, so we could see the equation you obtained?  Otherwise people have to reproduce your work.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+-+yz+%3D+3,+y%5E2+-+zx+%3D+4+,+z%5E2+-+xy+%3D+5) doesn't seem to have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
x^2y-y^2z=&\ 3y\\
y^2z-z^2x =&\ 4z\\
z^2x-x^2y =&\ 5x
\end{align}
then adding the three equations yields $3y+4z+5x = 0$. Likewise, we have
\begin{align}
x^2z-z^2y=&\ 3z\\
y^2x-x^2z =&\ 4x\\
z^2y-y^2x =&\ 5y
\end{align}
which gives $3z+4x+5y = 0$. Combining the two equations gives $z = 13y$. Substitute it back into the original equation (for instance equation 2, 3)
\begin{align}
y^2-13xy =&\ 4\\
13^3y^2-13xy =&\ 5*13
\end{align}
which leads to $y^2 = \frac{1}{36}$. The rest will follow immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  subtract each of the second and third equations from the previous one, then:

$$
x^2-y^2 +xz-yz=-1 \;\;\iff\;\; (x-y)(x+y+z)=-1\\
y^2-z^2 +xy-zx=-1 \;\;\iff\;\; (y-z)(x+y+z)=-1
$$

Therefore $\,x-y=y-z \iff y=(x+z)/2\,$, which reduces the system to two unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

We see that $$x^2-yz+z^2-xy-2(y^2-xz)=3+5-2\cdot4$$ or
$$(x+z)^2-(x+z)y-2y^2=0$$ or
$$(x+y+z)(x+z-2z)=0.$$
1. $x+y+z=0$ with the first and the second equations of our system.

We obtain $z=-x-y$, which gives

$x^2+xy+y^2=3$ and $x^2+xy+y^2=4$, which is impossible;

2. $x+z=2y$ or $z=2y-x$ with the first and the second equations of our system.

After this substitution we'll get the answer:
$$\left\{\left(\frac{11}{6},-\frac{1}{6},-\frac{13}{6}\right), \left(-\frac{11}{6},\frac{1}{6},\frac{13}{6}\right)\right\}$$